# jdbc error java class trying to connect to linux mysql server

Tags: mysql, jdbc

My error!

DBConnection2.java:38: unreported exception java.lang.InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

problem: .newInstance();

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class DBConnection2 {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://<myserver>/<myDatabase>";
    java.sql.Connection con = null;
    String query1;
    Statement stmt;

    public DBConnection2()
    {
        try
        {
//***error here*****  

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

 //***error here*****           
        }         
        catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
        {   
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        try                                   
        {                                    
            con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url,"read","read");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("SQLException:72 appserver " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what it says it is.  A new instance instantiation through reflection needs to be handled (caught or thrown).

That said, you aren't doing anything with the new instance - you aren't assigning it to anything and in this case, it doesn't even need to be called.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Just that - it will fix the error.

Realize that this still has other problems lurking in the code - one of which is if you have the error of not being able to load it the class, it will print out an error message, but then it will continue on in the next try block and error out *again* there.